I would like to change the height of my Sharepoint title image
I am using the Brand Central Sharepoint theme for my template. The "title image" gives the option for a "color block" or "image & title". I have chosen "color block" and am trying to put my logo within the teal block of color, but there is no option in the web part to add the image there. As a work around I considered using the "image & title" option and creating the graphic to embed the logo into that block before uploading it, but the image height is greatly reduced in this option.
Can anyone suggest a workaround to either A. use the "color block" option and add a logo image to the color block or B. increase the height of the image allowed in the "title & image" option?
Thanks in advance.
